# Picasso doesnot show placeholder, error and url image in imageview of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, picasso

I am trying to download a image into a imageview in a fragment but it doesnot show any image in the imageview, not even placeholder and error image. my code is the following in fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
       Picasso.with(c)
                .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg").
        placeholder(R.drawable.aa).error(R.drawable.ab)
                .into(imageView);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
```

when i try to use the same code in an normal activity everything works. the problem only seems with in  the fragment activity. i am using the imageview in swipe view  of material design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,
instead of this

```
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

try

```
          return view;
```

Comment: Happy to help       @sagar.acharya